# How to drive together JTA (Bitronix) and XADisk

Tags: java, transactions, jta

We have a J2SE application (we deploy it as a standalone JAR) which is a Jetty-powered web service, making use of JPA (EclipseLink) and JTA (Bitronix, UserTransaction). As you can guess, the main purpose of this app is to receive REST requests, process, store and provide data to the http clients.

While processing a request, sometimes we generate files on the fs. Sadly, this process is out of the scope of our JTA configuration. I have a task to bind file generation to the JTA transaction, eg. upon utx.rollback() I have to rollback file processing, and upon succesfull utx.commit() I have to commit the fs changes, too.

My senior advised me to use XADisk ( http://xadisk.java.net/ ). Seems very promising! I did some example-reading but I'm still a bit confused on how to introduce this into our app.
So my question: can anyone provide me some guidelines on how to implement this lib into a JTA application? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going forward on docs hunting, I found some bits of info:

[Tracking issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/XADISK-67)

[XADisk User Guide](http://java.net/downloads/xadisk/XADisk%201.2%20User%20Guide.pdf)

The latter contains a chapter titled "Enlisting XADisk into JTA Transactions"

Comment: plus, see if the reply (at aug20-2011) on [this](http://groups.google.com/group/xadisk/browse_thread/thread/e39b3292a36357c4/) thread helps.

Answer (score -1):

i have used XaDisk and i am very disappointed about rollback management.

See doc :

This exception is an unchecked exception thrown when a transaction is not able to continue its work and is left in an inconsistent incomplete state. That is, the transaction did not commit or rollback and will require an administrative intervention for resolving inconsistency and then marking the transaction as complete. A transaction can fail either during routine XADisk operations or during the recovery phase of XADisk. For the routine cases, the transaction will keep holding the locks (in-memory) over files/directories until it is marked complete.

It means that this lib actually doesnt do anything to reverse what has been created / deleted etc ...

quite useless

Comment: thats not entirely true, when an exception happens on session.commit() yes you do get that unchecked exception TransactionNotCompleteException.., however if exceptions happen before commit(), it does successfully roll back if session.rollback() its called.